# Where is Persoq's forest for "The Long Hunt"?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

After the arches I am being told to go to a forest with blackened trees.

Where is this location ?

Comment: North from Twin Elms; if you had Hiravias with you when you got this clue he'd tell you.